# Как объединить два if в одно

Tags: python, python-3.x

Типо Этого

```
if b == "TheMihai";c == "130471Ekb":
```

Comment: if b == "TheMihai" and c == "130471Ekb": ?

Answer (score -1):

```
if b == "TheMihai" or c == "130471Ekb":
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if b == "TheMihai" and c == "130471Ekb":
```

Answer (score -1):

Код вида:

```
if b == "TheMihai":
    if c == "130471Ekb":
        #делать что-то
```

Может быть упрощён путём объединения условий (предикатов):

```
if b == "TheMihai" and c == "130471Ekb":
    #делать что-то
```